# Selenium IE9 Access Denied Error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, selenium, internet-explorer-9, remotewebdriver

I am currently using Selenium and C# in visual studio 2010 to run tests using a remote web driver and Internet Explorer 9.

When I run the test, the command window will show and the initial start page for the webdriver server will show however this message below is then given and the test fails.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unexpected error launching Internet Explorer. IELaunchURL() returned HRESULT 80070005 ('Access is denied.') for URL 'http://localhost:5555/' (NoSuchDriver)
```

I have been looking for a solution to this however the only answers I found were to change the protected mode in the internet options so that they were all the same but this didn't work. The problem seems to appear randomly and then go away without me changing any settings at all. As a workaround I have stopped using the remote web driver and the tests seem to run ok.

Has anyone came across this problem when using the remote web driver before and have a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that the new updates/browser version was being applied to the computer so we just had to revert all updates and go back to the intended browser version which was IE9